# Is the transfer learning models trained on imagenet a good starting point to identify nutrient deficiencies in leaves?

Tags: tensorflow, transfer-learning

I am new to machine learning.  My machine learning goal is to identify a nutrient deficiency from analyzing images of plant leaves. From what I have found so far about machine learning model building techniques, the ideal is to use transfer learning. It seems most (all?) available transfer learning models have been trained on imagenet.

As shown in this [colab notebook](https://gist.github.com/solarslurpi/1af79154820e1bcb95ea2e640351849b), the transfer learning model trained on imagenet returns the classification of 'brambling' for the leaf image. No, the image is not a small finch.

How should I interpret this misclassification? Is transfer learning still the right way to proceed? What should I be thinking about/gaining a better understanding before I continue modeling for nutrient deficiencies based on leaf images?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The model is trained on imagenet and it is a good starting point. However your model needs to be specifically trained further for the problem you are trying to solve. You can not just use model.predict and expect it to classify correctly. Therefore you need to create a dataset that will be used to train your model. For example lets say you are trying to classify images of tomato plant into 2 classes, health and diseased. To do that you need to gather images of healthy tomato leaves and images of diseased tomato leaves. First create a directory called tomatoes. Then create two sub directories healthy and diseased.  On Google or Bing do a search for healthy tomato leaf images. Download at least a hundred of these images and place them in the healthy sub directory. The do a search for diseased tomato leaf images. Again download at least 100 of these and place the images in the diseased sub directory. Now you have a data set from which to train your model. (Note in the app stores you can find applications that will download an entire page of images).
Now use the code below to create the train, test and validation data sets

```
def preprocess (sdir, trsplit, vsplit, random_seed):
    filepaths=[]
    labels=[]    
    classlist=os.listdir(sdir)
    for klass in classlist:
        classpath=os.path.join(sdir,klass)
        flist=os.listdir(classpath)
        for f in flist:
            fpath=os.path.join(classpath,f)
            filepaths.append(fpath)
            labels.append(klass)
    Fseries=pd.Series(filepaths, name='filepaths')
    Lseries=pd.Series(labels, name='labels')
    df=pd.concat([Fseries, Lseries], axis=1)       
    # split df into train_df and test_df 
    dsplit=vsplit/(1-trsplit)
    strat=df['labels']    
    train_df, dummy_df=train_test_split(df, train_size=trsplit, shuffle=True, random_state=random_seed, stratify=strat)
    strat=dummy_df['labels']
    valid_df, test_df=train_test_split(dummy_df, train_size=dsplit, shuffle=True, random_state=random_seed, stratify=strat)
    print('train_df length: ', len(train_df), '  test_df length: ',len(test_df), '  valid_df length: ', len(valid_df))
     # check that each dataframe has the same number of classes to prevent model.fit errors
    trcount=len(train_df['labels'].unique())
    tecount=len(test_df['labels'].unique())
    vcount=len(valid_df['labels'].unique())
    if trcount != tecount :         
        msg='** WARNING ** number of classes in training set not equal to number of classes in test set'
        print_in_color(msg, (255,0,0), (55,65,80))
        msg='This will throw an error in either model.evaluate or model.predict'
        print_in_color(msg, (255,0,0), (55,65,80))
    if trcount != vcount:
        msg='** WARNING ** number of classes in training set not equal to number of classes in validation set' 
        print_in_color(msg, (255,0,0), (55,65,80))
        msg=' this will throw an error in model.fit'
        print_in_color(msg, (255,0,0), (55,65,80))
        print ('train df class count: ', trcount, 'test df class count: ', tecount, ' valid df class count: ', vcount) 
    ans=input('Enter C to continue execution or H to halt execution')
    if ans =='H' or ans == 'h':
        print_in_color('Halting Execution', (255,0,0), (55,65,80))
        import sys
        sys.exit('program halted by user')            
    print(list(train_df['labels'].value_counts()))
    return train_df, test_df, valid_df

sdir=r'c:\tomatoes'
train_df, test_df, valid_df= preprocess(sdir, .8,.1, 123)
```

now you need to create 3 generators with the code below

```
working_dir = sdir
img_size=(224,224) 
channels=3
batch_size=30
img_shape=(img_size[0], img_size[1], channels)
length=len(test_df)
test_batch_size=sorted([int(length/n) for n in range(1,length+1) if length % n ==0 and length/n<=80],reverse=True)[0]  
test_steps=int(length/test_batch_size)
print ( 'test batch size: ' ,test_batch_size, '  test steps: ', test_steps)
def scalar(img):    
    return img  # EfficientNet expects pixelsin range 0 to 255 so no scaling is required
trgen=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=scalar, horizontal_flip=True)
tvgen=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=scalar)
train_gen=trgen.flow_from_dataframe( train_df, x_col='filepaths', y_col='labels', target_size=img_size, class_mode='categorical',
                                    color_mode='rgb', shuffle=True, batch_size=batch_size)
test_gen=tvgen.flow_from_dataframe( test_df, x_col='filepaths', y_col='labels', target_size=img_size, class_mode='categorical',
                                    color_mode='rgb', shuffle=False, batch_size=test_batch_size)

valid_gen=tvgen.flow_from_dataframe( valid_df, x_col='filepaths', y_col='labels', target_size=img_size, class_mode='categorical',
                                    color_mode='rgb', shuffle=True, batch_size=batch_size)
classes=list(train_gen.class_indices.keys())
class_count=len(classes)
```

Now use the code below to create a good model

```
model_name='EfficientNetB3'
base_model=tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB2(include_top=False, weights="imagenet",input_shape=img_shape, pooling='max') 
x=base_model.output
x=keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99, epsilon=0.001 )(x)
x = Dense(256, kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(l = 0.016),activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.006),
                bias_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.006) ,activation='relu')(x)
x=Dropout(rate=.45, seed=123)(x)        
output=Dense(class_count, activation='softmax')(x)
model=Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=output)
model.compile(Adamax(lr=.001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

now train your model with the code below

```
epochs = 15
history=model.fit(x=train_gen,  epochs=epochs, verbose=1, 
                  validation_data=valid_gen,
                  validation_steps=None,  shuffle=False,  initial_epoch=0)
```

you model will train for 15 epochs and since this is a simple data set it
should do well but check to make sure with the code below

```
acc=model.evaluate( test_gen, verbose=1, steps=test_steps, return_dict=False)[1]*100
msg=f'accuracy on the test set is {acc:5.2f} %'
print(msg)
```

You should get an accuracy in the 90's % range.
Now we will use the model to predict a single image

```
fpath=r'c:\tomatoes\...etc # path to the tomato leaf image you want to predict
img=cv2.imread(fpath)
img=cv2.resize(img, img_size)
img=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) 
display_img=img/255
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(display_img)     
prediction=model.predict(img, verbose=1)
index=np.argmax(prediction)
klass=classes[index]
print ('The leaf is of class ', klass)
```

finally save your model

```
save_id=str (EfficientNetB3 +  '-tomatoes-.h5' 
model_save_loc=os.path.join(sdir, save_id)
model.save(model_save_loc)
print ('model was saved as ' ,  model_save_loc)
```

you will need to import these modules

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation,Dropout,Conv2D, MaxPooling2D,BatchNormalization, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam, Adamax
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, load_model, Sequential
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import cv2 as cv2
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: Thank you...I've built a similar model.  I was more wondering why the starting point was so far off.  I need to explore/understand your code a bit more.  I have used data augmentation with imageDataGenerator... so I seem to be headed in the right direction.  Again, thank you.

Comment: some people initially set base_model.trainable=False, train for 5 to 10 epochs then set base_model_trainable=True and train for more epochs. This is called fine tuning. However I find leaving the base_model as trainable initially gets to a lower validation loss in the same number of total epochs

Comment: Thank you very much.  I appreciate your help!